# How to prove one set is a dense subalgebra of $C(X)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Show $A$=span{$e^{nx}: n\in Z$} is a dense subalgebra of $C([0,1])$

First $f,g \in A, fg \in A$

Then for $x_{1}\not = x_{2}, f\in A, f(x_{1}) \not = f(x_{2}) $

And ${1} \in A$

Is my proof right? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using Stone--Weierstrass theorem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to apply the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, as the Weierstrass theorem suffices.

We can limit ourselves to $A_N={\rm span}\,\{e^{nx}\,:\, n\ge N\}$ for an arbitrary natural number $N,$ for example $N=2022.$ Let $f\in C[0,1].$ Then the function $g(t)=t^{-N}\,f(\log t)$ belongs the space $C[1,e].$ By the Weierstrass theorem there exists a sequence of polynomials $p_n(t)$ uniformly convergent to $g(t).$ Equivalently the sequence of functions $p_n(e^x)$ is uniformly convergent to $g(e^x)=e^{-Nx}f(x),$ for $0\le x\le 1.$ Thus the sequence $e^{Nx}p_n(e^x)$ is uniformly convergent to $f(x),$ and $e^{Nx}p_n(e^x)\in A_N.$